# String to Array won't work

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode

I have a large string of numbers (~25'000) that looks like so:

```
$numbers = "612000 709178 334770 640133 782189 711197 343667 715231 82900 713737 780729 717491 629803 711003 317252 711074 713740 429159 351816 5719 338126 715246";
```

I want to create an array. I thought that would  be very simple. So I did:

```
$myarr = explode(" ", $numbers);

print_r($myarr);
```

Result:

```
Array ( [0] => 612000 709178 334770 640133 782189 711197 343667 715231 82900 713737 780729 717491 629803 711003 317252 711074 713740 429159 351816 5719 338126 715246 )
```

But i should be:

```
Array ( [0] => 612000 [1] => 709178 [2] => 334770 [3] => 640133 [4] => 782189 [5] => 711197 [6] => 343667 [7] => 715231 [8] => 82900 [9] => 713737 [10] => 780729 [11] => 717491 [12] => 629803 [13] => 711003 [14] => 317252 [15] => 711074 [16] => 713740 [17] => 429159 [18] => 351816 [19] => 5719 [20] => 338126 [21] =>  715246 )
```

What am I doing wrong? I saw many examples. (e.g. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: Are you sure it's space and not tab delimited?

Comment: Your example is working for me.

Comment: [Working Fine](http://codepad.viper-7.com/xoHICE). `var_dump($numbers);` & make sure strings are separated by the space.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson How can I check that? The numbers output comes from a system command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work. As pointed out in the comments, it might not be a space in between the items. One solution(although much slower) is to use `preg_split`

```
$myArr= preg_split("/[\s]+/", $numbers);
```

This just splits on white space. It would be better if you could just split using explode and the correct character, but if you don't know what kind of white space to expect, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$numbers = "612000 709178 334770 640133 782189 711197 343667 715231 82900 713737 780729 717491 629803 711003 317252 711074 713740 429159 351816 5719 338126 715246";

$numbers = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$numbers);

$myarr = explode(" ", $numbers);

print_r($myarr);
```

if you may be included more than two spaces this code works